# Add WordPress Featered Image to JSON encode array

Tags: json, wordpress

I am using WP_Query and json_encode to return the WordPress post data in a JSON array so that I can use Angular.js as a front end. Everything works, except that I am not able to include the featured image in the JSON file. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php 

function test_ajax()
{
    header( "content-type: applications/json" );
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'order'=> 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id')
    ) ) );
    echo json_encode($query->get_posts());
    die();
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_test_ajax", "test_ajax");
add_action("wp_ajax_test_ajax", "test_ajax");
```

Here is the json that is outputted:

```
[{
"ID":133,
"post_author":"1",
"post_date":"2014-08-19 05:54:03",
"post_date_gmt":"2014-08-19 05:54:03",
"post_content":"\"Woman",
"post_title":"Woman on the Banks of the Seine, After Courbet, 1950",
"post_excerpt":"",
"post_status":"publish",
"comment_status":"open",
"ping_status":"open",
"post_password":"",
"post_name":"woman-on-the-banks-of-the-seine-after-courbet-1950",
"to_ping":"",
"pinged":"",
"post_modified":"2014-08-19 05:54:03",
"post_modified_gmt":"2014-08-19 05:54:03",
"post_content_filtered":"",
"post_parent":0,
"guid":"http:\/\/localhost\/mabs\/?p=133",
"menu_order":0,
"post_type":"post",
"post_mime_type":"",
"comment_count":"0",
"filter":"raw"
}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch all WordPress posts with featured image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438118/how-to-fetch-all-wordpress-posts-with-featured-image)

Comment: Seems like that should work but it doesn't.